# Sum of two column from different table and it should return result if secondary table does not have any data

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have two tables : Tb_PurchaseProductDetail(primary key: id), tb_productstockupdate(foreign key: PurchaseProductId (having relationship with Tb_PurchaseProductDetail table primary key)).
Now i want sum of two column value of Tb_PurchaseProductDetail table and one column of tb_productstockupdate table in a relationship (). below query giving me correct data if any single row exist in tb_productstockupdate table but if no data available in tb_productstockupdate table than it is not returning data from primary table.

i am expecting that if no data exist in secondary table than at least it should return data on the basis of primary table.

```
s.tb_productstockupdate.Sum(d => d.StockDifference))
```

above code should return 0 instead of null.

Below is the code what i am using. I don't know what i am missing.

```
connectionObj.Tb_PurchaseProductDetail.Where(s => s.ProductId == prodcutId && ((s.Quantity + s.DiscountQuantity + s.tb_productstockupdate.Sum(d => d.StockDifference)) > s.SoldPackQuantity)).Select(s => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = s.BatchNumber + " [(" + (s.Quantity + s.DiscountQuantity + s.tb_productstockupdate.Sum(d => d.StockDifference) - s.SoldPackQuantity) + ") & " + s.ExpiryDate + "]",
                Value = s.Id.ToString()
            }).ToList();
```

Below code solved my problem. I used Any() to check if secondary table is having data or not and place my logic accordingly.

```
connectionObj.Tb_PurchaseProductDetail.Where(s => s.ProductId == prodcutId && ((s.Quantity + s.DiscountQuantity + (s.tb_productstockupdate.Any() ? s.tb_productstockupdate.Select(d => d.StockDifference).Sum() : 0)) > s.SoldPackQuantity)).Select(s => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = s.BatchNumber + " [(" + (s.Quantity + s.DiscountQuantity + (s.tb_productstockupdate.Any()? s.tb_productstockupdate.Sum(d => d.StockDifference) : 0) - s.SoldPackQuantity) + ") & " + s.ExpiryDate + "]",
                Value = s.Id.ToString()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved my problem. I used Any() to check if secondary table is having data or not and used ternary operator accordingly.

```
connectionObj.Tb_PurchaseProductDetail.Where(s => s.ProductId == prodcutId && ((s.Quantity + s.DiscountQuantity + (s.tb_productstockupdate.Any() ? s.tb_productstockupdate.Select(d => d.StockDifference).Sum() : 0)) > s.SoldPackQuantity)).Select(s => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = s.BatchNumber + " [(" + (s.Quantity + s.DiscountQuantity + (s.tb_productstockupdate.Any()? s.tb_productstockupdate.Sum(d => d.StockDifference) : 0) - s.SoldPackQuantity) + ") & " + s.ExpiryDate + "]",
                Value = s.Id.ToString()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have `PurchaseProducts` and `ProductStocks`, and there is a one-to-many relation between them: every `PurchaseProduct` has zero or more `ProductStocks`, every `ProductStock` belongs to exactly one `PurchaseProduct`: the one that the foreign key `PurchaseProductId` points to.

Every `PurchaseProduct` also has at least two properties, let's as A and B. Every `ProductStock` has at least a property C.

> **Requirement**: give me from every PurchaseProduct with all its ProductStocks the sum of A and B and all its ProductStocks C

If you've followed the [entity framework code first conventions,](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) you will have something similar as below

```
class PurchaseProduct
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public double A {get; set;}
    public double B {get; set;}
    ...

    // every PurchaseProduct has zero or more ProductStocks (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<ProductStock> ProductStocks {get; set;}
}
class ProductStock
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public double C {get; set;}
    ...

    // every ProductStock belongs to exactly one PurchaseProduct, using foreign key
    public int PurchaseProductId {get; set;}
    public virtual PurchaseProduct PurchaseProduct {get; set;}
}
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<PurchaseProduct> PurchaseProducts {get; set;}
     public DbSet<ProductStock> ProductStocks {get; set;}
}
```

This is all that entity framework needs to know to detect your tables, the columns in the tables, the relations between the tables and the primary and foreign keys.

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

Having defined your classes your query is simple.

```
var result = myDbContext.PurchaseProducts
    .Where(purchaseProduct => ...)         // only if you don't want all PurchaseProducts

    // from every remaining PurchaseProduct calculate A + B + Sum(all C of its ProductStocks)
    .Select(purchaseProduct => purchaseProduct.A + purchaseProduct.B
            + purchaseProduct.ProductStocks
                             .Select(productStock => productStock.C)
                             .Sum());
```

Entity framework knows the relation between PurchaseProducts and ProductStocks, and knows that a groupJoin is needed.

Note that every purchaseProduct has an A and a B. You will always get at least A+B. If the purchaseProduct has no ProductStocks at all, then purchaseProduct.ProductStocks will be an empty collection. The Select and the Sum will result in a zero value.

Some people don't trust entity framework and prefer to do the group-join themselves:

```
var result = myDbContext.PurchaseProducts.GroupJoin(
    myDbContext.ProductStocks,

    purchaseProduct => purchaseProduct.Id,          // from every PurchaseProduct take the Id
    productStock => productStock.PurchaseProductId, // from every ProductStock take the foreign key

    // ResultSelector: from every PurchaseProducts, with all its matching ProductStocks
    // calculate A + B + Sum of all C of the productStocks
    (purchaseProduct, productStocksOfThisPurchaseProduct) =>
    purchaseProduct.A + purchaseProduct.B +
    productStocksOfThisPurchaseProduct.Select(productStock => productStock.C).Sum());
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Thanks for your response. But that will not work for me. in my query please see **where** condition where i need to compare quantity with **soldpackquantity**. Here if secondary table does not contain any data than it should compare soldpackquantity to primary table quantity and should return data in list format.

Here what happen if secondary table doesn't contain any data than it is not returning row as per primary table. I run the query in sql and found if ```s.tb_productstockupdate.Sum(d => d.StockDifference))``` will return 0 than it will work fine. right now it is returning null.